# How to call private method which accepts Map as an input parameter using Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, dictionary

I am trying to use reflection to call a private Method in one of my class which also accepts a Map parameter.

Below is the method which I am supposed to call, and below method is in `ReflectionTest`:

```
private static Map<String, String> storageSort(final List<Map<String, String>> employeeList) {

}
```

I am calling the above method like this:

```
ReflectionTest io = new ReflectionTest();
Method m = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("storageSort", Map.class);
m.setAccessible(true); 
Object o = m.invoke(io, sortList);
```

But below is the exception I am getting everytime:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.reflection.test.ReflectionTest.storageSort(java.util.Map)

I am not sure what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: The method accepts a `List` parameter.

Comment: Change `Map.class` to `List.class`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis make that an answer.. I'll upvote you :-D

Comment: Silly mistake from me.. Need to take a nap now I guess..

Comment: Yes, it happens from time to time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method clearly takes a `List` parameter.

```
Method m = Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("storageSort", List.class);
```

Comment: While this is indeed the answer, I'm amazed how people doesn't even care to read their own code =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ironic, as you probably didn't read that comment before you posted it. :P

Comment: @JoshM which comment?